# Relative Path for Typescript module import pointing to wrong Directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, relative-path, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I have an application layer written in [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) using [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript).  I also have Web Resources that are built using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [html](/questions/tagged/html).  The html for the Web Resources use [requirejs](/questions/tagged/requirejs) to include the compiled Typescript code wherever necessary. The problem I am seeing is with the relative paths I am using in my Typescript.  When I publish the Web Resources to Microsoft Dynamics, RequireJS is attempting to load the relative paths from my Typescript relative to the html file rather than relative to the transpiled Javascript file.

### WebAPI

*Transpiled to build/CCSEQ/WebAPI.js (Model.js is located at build/CCSEQ/Model.js)*

```
"use strict";

import * as Model from "./Model.js";

export class WebAPI{
  // Code here
}
```

### Main.html

*Located at /WebResources/html/Main.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Main</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <script src="require.js" data-main="../js/Main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Main.js

*Located at /WebResources/js/Main.js*

```
"use strict";

// Require fails because it is looking for /WebResources/html/Model.js rather than /build/CCSEQ/Model.js
require(["WebAPI.js"], function(WebApi){
  // Code Here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**The first thing you should do is drop the `.js` from your module names (both your `require` call and your `import` statement).** The names you pass in `require` and `define` are module names. They look like paths but they are not really paths. RequireJS takes the module names and transforms them to paths using the `map`, `paths` and `baseUrl` configuration options (to name the ones used most frequently). When you do not use these options, it uses sensible defaults.

If you do use `.js` in a *module name*, RequireJS assumes you are passing a path rather than an actual module name. (The same is true if you start the string with a slash, use a query parameter like in (`foo?blah`), or if you have a colon in the string, which RequireJS takes as indication that you are using a protocol (e.g. `http://`).) In this case, there is no transformation of a module name to a path so `map`, `paths` and `baseUrl` are all ignored. Here is the piece of [code](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/blob/f2335026867afd80c394247bfe5278d2bd8f32ee/require.js#L1640):

```
        //If a colon is in the URL, it indicates a protocol is used and it is just
        //an URL to a file, or if it starts with a slash, contains a query arg (i.e. ?)
        //or ends with .js, then assume the user meant to use an url and not a module id.
        //The slash is important for protocol-less URLs as well as full paths.
        if (req.jsExtRegExp.test(moduleName)) {
            //Just a plain path, not module name lookup, so just return it.
            //Add extension if it is included. This is a bit wonky, only non-.js things pass
            //an extension, this method probably needs to be reworked.
            url = moduleName + (ext || '');
        } else {
```

The value of `req.jsExtRegExp` is `/^\/|:|\?|\.js$/`.

(You can keep your `.js` in the value you pass to `data-main` because `data-main` is special.)

**Moreover, you need to do something so that `require(["WebAPI"]...` will resolve to a correct path.** You can do this by setting a `baseUrl` in your RequireJS configuration that points to the directory that contains the file `WebAPI.js`. Or you can use `paths`:

```
paths: {
  WebAPI: '../../build/CCSEQ/WebAPI',
}
```

Note how the value for the key `WebAPI` also lacks the `.js` extension. You must not have it there either. The value there is a path (not a module name) and the issue you'll have if you put `.js` there is that RequireJS will try to find a file with the `.js.js` extension!

If you want to read more about the difference between module names (aka module ids) and paths, I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31072055/1906307) that goes over that specifically.